# webpack-url-loader ignores subfolders

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

We are currently extending our build pipeline for a vue.js application and have some challanges with our webpack-configuration.

Our images are stored inside an *images*-subdirectory. Depending on the image quality we have subfolders in our *image*-directory. The url-loader doesn't seem to be smart enough to include subfolders, so we've tried to define additional rules for each subfolder.

```
{
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
  loader: 'url-loader',
  options: {
   limit: -1,
   name: utils.assetsPath('assets/images/low/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
  }
}
```

Unfortunately the result isn't pleasant since all images inside of the *image*-directory will be placed inside the subfolder as well whereas all images stored in the base directory seem to be damaged in our *dist* folder.

How we can include subfolders in our *url-loader*-rules?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find the solution?

Comment: @Borjante It was difficult to find an appropriate solution. My final approach is based on the technique in this thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47677256/path-to-static-assets-in-vue-js-application). But nevertheless it is required to overwrite the final paths inside the stylesheet after the build process is finished. We did it with our deployment script (a c# linqpad-script).

Comment: No way my friend, found out it was pretty simple in the end. Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to prepend [path] no the filename :)

```js
{
  test: /\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$/,
  loader: 'url-loader',
  options: {
    limit: 10000,
    name: '[path][name].[ext]?[hash]',
    publicPath: isProd ? 'https://d267jrn1ysxlb3.cloudfront.net' : ''
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Borjante! That did the job.